# Elo rating: how many comparisons necessary to achieve accurate rating with n players given no prior knowledge?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, rating, elo

If I have *n* participants in a two-player-game league, whose initial ratings are unknown, is there a good heuristic for how many games/comparisons/pair-faceoffs are required to achieve an accurate rating with the [Elo rating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system)? How does it scale with tens, hundreds or even thousands of participants?

Comment: Elo wrote about aspects of this in the original articles popularizing the method.  Among other things, he noted the importance of having a well connected game graph: if the players form playing cliques with little or no games between cliques, comparing ratings in different cliques is problematic.  The precision of a rating will also depend on whether the player has played against comparably rated players.  What good would it do for an average player to play a thousand games against grandmaster opponents only, for instance?